# adding characters to dir output

Tags: windows, command-line

is there any way to add characters to `dir` output?

for example

C:\temp\temp>dir /B

outputs:

> file1.txt
>
> file2.txt

I would like it to add the word "file" and surround filename in single quotes (from within a batch file)

hopeful/expected output would be:

> file 'file1.txt'
>
> file 'file2.txt'

Eventually I will use > to export this to a txt file then pass that text file to ffmpeg as a parameter.  I tried [FART](https://emtunc.org/blog/03/2011/farting-the-easy-way-find-and-replace-text/) however I couldn't add characters to the beginning of the line.

seems like this should be a fairly common use case, listing files in a directory to use for input to another program.  but how would I get these extra characters in there?  ("file" and single quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I would like it to add the word "file" and surround filename in single quotes

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b') do (
  echo file '%%f'
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is Seagate 1
 Volume Serial Number is 1A87-3A15

 Directory of F:\test\test

16/04/2020  22:20    <DIR>          .
16/04/2020  22:20    <DIR>          ..
10/06/2020  18:17                 0 file1.txt
10/06/2020  18:17                 0 file2.txt
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  44,023,545,856 bytes free

F:\test\test>..\test.cmd
file 'file1.txt'
file 'file2.txt'
F:\test\test>
```

To export to a text file (eg `test.out`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b') do (
  echo file '%%f' >> test.out
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test\test>..\test.cmd
F:\test\test>type test.out
file 'file1.txt'
file 'file2.txt'

F:\test\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)